# Android self-signed handshake error

Tags: android, ssl, https

I'm trying to do a POST HTTP request on a HTTPS server with a self-signed certificate. My POST is multipart to allow to send a file (picture or anything else).

I'm still getting the following error:

```
Error:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed:Handshake failed
```

Here is my source code:

```
URL url = new URL(PROTOCOL + "://" + host + "/file");
URI uri = new URI(PROTOCOL, null, url.getHost(), url.getPort(), URLEncoder.encode(url.getPath(), "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20").replace("%2F", "/"), url.getQuery(), null);
String authorizationHeader = Hawk.generateAuthorizationHeader(url, "POST", (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000), Hawk.generateNonce(), url.getPort());

HttpClient client = getHttpClient();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", authorizationHeader);

MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

java.io.File file = new java.io.File(fullLocalFilePath);
entityBuilder.addBinaryBody(fullLocalFilePath, file);

HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
httpPost.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
httpEntity.consumeContent();
```

Comment: Do you have access to the logs of the SSL server ? If so, you should post them too

Comment: Sorry not yet. I could have access but not before some days/weeks. I will restart a bounty if there is no additional answer

Comment: are you able to simply make a get call to the https url ? can you share what is the output of that call ?

Comment: Yes, I can make a simple GET on the url. The output is a standard JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered something like this before, so here's my guess. The issue is that the certificate is using a different domain than where I'm currently using it. In OpenSSL, the domain name is the `Common Name` which it will ask you when creating the certificate, or if doing it as a parameter, it is the `CN`. The value of this should be the same as the domain of the server that you are trying to access.

You may try this:
For windows, go to `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc`, edit `hosts` as an administrator. Add a line something like this `<your IP>     mysampledomain.net`, then when creating your SSL key/certificate, put `mysampledomain.net` as the value of the domain name i.e. `Common Name` in OpenSSL parameters. For linux, the procedure is the same, except that the `hosts` file is located in `/etc/hosts`.

Try invoking your code and see if you still get the same error.